# Get block device parent

Tags: linux, block-device

Given a block device, how can I get its "parent"?

A example would be a LUKS virtual decrypted device (/dev/mapper/decrypted), whose parent would be the encrypted block device (/dev/sdb)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For non-interactive work, this can be done using `dmsetup deps`, which lists the block device's dependencies. By default, it'll return the major:minor device numbers, but you can provide additional options to output a name:

```
dmsetup deps -o devname /dev/mapper/decrypted
```

For doing this interactively, the best way is just to use `lsblk`, which outputs a nicely formatted graph:

```
└─sda8                     8:8    0  43.9G  0 part  
  └─sda8_crypt           253:2    0  43.9G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgpersonal-home    253:3    0    83G  0 lvm
```

Comment: I think the output of `dmsetup deps` is not very complete: For example when I specify a logical volume, I just get the name of the disk partition (like `sda8`). Is there a command to get all parents, children, and siblings? Re-using dmsetup does not work: For example `dmsetup deps -o devname /dev/sda8` falsely claims `Device sda8 not found`. Of course it exists!

Comment: @U.Windl `/dev/sda8` is very likely representing hardware, not a devicemapper blockdevice, so `dmsetup` can't possibly work there (as it states, the device doesn't exist, as far as devicemapper is concerned). Did you try using `lsblk`, which I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: In my view sda8 is not actual hardware, but sda would be: Without an sda, there would not be an sda8, so sda8 is a child of sda, and sda is a parent of sda8.

Comment: @U.Windl And that's exactly [what you get with `lsblk`](https://pastebin.com/YbYpieXw) :)